# Why changing canvas size resets its parameters?

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, mozilla

When I change the canvas size, I notice the parameter 'mozImageSmoothingEnabled' is being reset.

HTML

```
<canvas id='canv'>Your browser don't support canvas.</canvas>
```

Javascript

```
var cnv = document.getElementById('canv');
var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
console.log(ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled); // default 'true'
ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
console.log(ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled); // shows 'false'
cnv.width = 100;
console.log(ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled); // shows 'true'
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/epvtuz37/

Is this a bug, or expected behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because when you change the canvas `width` or `height` parameters, **every** properties of the attached context are reset to their default.

[From specs](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/spec/the-canvas-element.html)

> When the canvas element is created, and subsequently whenever the width and height attributes are set (whether to a new value or to the previous value), the bitmap and any associated contexts must be cleared back to their initial state and reinitialized with the newly specified coordinate space dimensions.

Comment: Thanks. But is this expected? What's the rationale behind it?

Comment: Yes it is expected, the rationale is that the context is based on a pixel matrix, if you change this pixel matrix, everything else has to be reset.

Comment: Right. Thank you!