# Can not change the font size using html5-canvas and Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need one help. I need to increase the font size using canvas and Javascript. I am explaining my code below.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = "40px Calibri";
  var y=10;
  var cnt=0;
  var bg;
  var logo;
  var bgLoaded = false;
  var logoLoaded = false;
var dataURL='';
var str='Valid:'+$('#validfrm').val()+'-'+$('#validto').val();
canvas.width = bg.width;
canvas.height = bg.height;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(logo, 20, 130);
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillText($('#copTitle').val(), 160, 70);
ctx.fillText($('#coupondiscount').val(), 190, 110);
 ctx.fillText($('#couponmessage').val(), 190, 150);
 ctx.fillText(str, 60, 280);
```

Here I have set the high font size but the small text size is coming. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: did you try with different font, doesit work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why changing canvas size resets the mozImageSmoothingEnabled parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732357/why-changing-canvas-size-resets-the-mozimagesmoothingenabled-parameter)

Comment: I can't say for sure this will work but did you try `ctx.style.font` ?

Comment: Set your canvas `width` and `height` **before** setting any of your `ctx` properties. In case you need to set your canvas size relative to some values of your ctx with certain properties set (e.g `ctx.font = '40px Arial'; canvas.width = ctx.measureText('str').width;`) then you need to set all the properties of your `ctx` again **after** you've changed the canvas' size.