# ctx.strokeStyle is not working in canvas html 5

Tags: reactjs, colors, html5-canvas

I am creating an White-board application and I am tying to draw with my mouse using different color pen.
I was trying to use ctx.strokeStyle to change the color of pen but for some reason it is not working.
I try changing other properties of pen and they are also not changing like thickness

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const WhiteBoard = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false);
  const [context, setContext] = useState(null);
  const [prevX, setPrevX] = useState(0);
  const [prevY, setPrevY] = useState(0);

  const divRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    setContext(ctx);
    
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    console.log(ctx.strokeStyle,'here I am ');
    console.log("Stroke style set to:", );
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    const canvasdiv = divRef.current;

    // const canvasheight=canvasdiv.offsetHeight;
    // const canvaswidth=canvasdiv.offsetWidth;
    //Will get the height and width including border and margin

    //Excludes border and margin
    const canvasheight = canvasdiv.clientHeight;
    const canvaswidth = canvasdiv.clientWidth;

    canvas.width = canvaswidth;
    canvas.height = canvasheight;
  }, []);

  const startDrawing = (e) => {
    setIsDrawing(true);
    setPrevX(e.nativeEvent.offsetX);
    setPrevY(e.nativeEvent.offsetY);
  };

  const draw = (e) => {
    if (!isDrawing) return;

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    context.lineTo(e.nativeEvent.offsetX, e.nativeEvent.offsetY);
    context.stroke();

    setPrevX(e.nativeEvent.offsetX);
    setPrevY(e.nativeEvent.offsetY);
  };

  const stopDrawing = () => {
    setIsDrawing(false);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={divRef} className="w-100">
      <canvas
        ref={canvasRef}
        className="w-100"
        onMouseDown={startDrawing}
        onMouseMove={draw}
        onMouseUp={stopDrawing}
        onMouseOut={stopDrawing}
        style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
      ></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WhiteBoard;
```

The output of the console.log is #ff0000 so altest it has the value.

Comment: have you tried to move ```setContext(ctx);``` to the end of ```useEffect``` ?

Comment: Just tried it still the same @cantdocpp I really don't understand why it is happening I was working like tomorrow but today it just stop updating anything related to line color or width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the canvas height and width destroys the style you've previously set on the context. Try setting the width/height first, then applying the style:

```js
const {useEffect, useRef, useState} = React;

const WhiteBoard = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false);
  const [context, setContext] = useState(null);
  const [prevX, setPrevX] = useState(0);
  const [prevY, setPrevY] = useState(0);
  const divRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const canvasdiv = divRef.current;
    const canvasheight = canvasdiv.clientHeight;
    const canvaswidth = canvasdiv.clientWidth;
    canvas.width = canvaswidth;
    canvas.height = canvasheight;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    setContext(ctx);
  }, []);

  const startDrawing = (e) => {
    setIsDrawing(true);
    setPrevX(e.nativeEvent.offsetX);
    setPrevY(e.nativeEvent.offsetY);
  };

  const draw = (e) => {
    if (!isDrawing) return;

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    context.lineTo(e.nativeEvent.offsetX, e.nativeEvent.offsetY);
    context.stroke();

    setPrevX(e.nativeEvent.offsetX);
    setPrevY(e.nativeEvent.offsetY);
  };

  const stopDrawing = () => {
    setIsDrawing(false);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={divRef} className="w-100">
      <canvas
        ref={canvasRef}
        className="w-100"
        onMouseDown={startDrawing}
        onMouseMove={draw}
        onMouseUp={stopDrawing}
        onMouseOut={stopDrawing}
        style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
      ></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<WhiteBoard />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Note that where you call `setContext(ctx)` doesn't really matter, although it seems best style to do that at the end of the function to communicate that that's the state for the *next* render.

Here's a minimal example, which shows that the problem is unrelated to React:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const draw = resize => {
  ctx.reset();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;

  if (resize) {
    // destroys styles set above
    canvas.width = 300;
  }

  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 100);
  ctx.stroke();
};
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="draw(true)">Draw with resize</button>
  <button onclick="draw()">Draw without resize</button>
</div>
<canvas height="150" width="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank You It explains a lot. Can you also tell why setting height and width destroys the style of the canvas

Comment: No problem. That's just how the canvas works per the spec. See [Why changing canvas size resets its parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732357/why-changing-canvas-size-resets-its-parameters/40732474#40732474)

Answer (score 1):

Change your `useEffect` function to this code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const canvasdiv = divRef.current;

    // const canvasheight=canvasdiv.offsetHeight;
    // const canvaswidth=canvasdiv.offsetWidth;
    //Will get the height and width including border and margin

    //Excludes border and margin
    const canvasheight = canvasdiv.clientHeight;
    const canvaswidth = canvasdiv.clientWidth;

    canvas.width = canvaswidth;
    canvas.height = canvasheight;
    
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
    console.log(ctx.strokeStyle,'here I am ');
    console.log("Stroke style set to:", ctx);
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    
    setContext(ctx);
  }, []);
```

Basically, I just reverse the order of your code. So you change your `ctx` at the end of `useEffect`

Hope it helps you

Comment: Can you also please tell why reversing the order works thanks

Comment: Changing canvas width and height will reset the previous styling. So you better do it first